# Local variables in Bash like in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

It seams wrong to repeat the same string twice

```
grep -q '+::::::' /etc/passwd || echo '+::::::' >> /etc/passwd
```

but if I do

```
{
local a='+::::::'
local b="/etc/passwd"
grep -q $a $b || echo $a >> $b
}
```

bash complains

```
-bash: local: can only be used in a function
```

**Question**

Is there a way to do local variables in Bash similar to how Perl does with the `{ ... }`?

Comment: You can try `var_name=var_$RANDOM` & then use `eval $var_name=value` for assignment & `${!varname}` to de-reference... Then unset `$var_name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific example, you can use a subshell, which effectively localizes *all* variables assigned within.

```
(
a='+::::::'
b="/etc/passwd"
grep -q "$a" "$b" || echo "$a" >> "$b"
)
```

Comment: In BASH 3 even `local` is allowed inside `{ and }` I am using `3.2.51`

Comment: @anubhava `local` does not work inside a `{...}` compound command that isn't the body of a function definition.

Comment: I wouldn't have commented without testing. That is the behavior I notice in `bash 3.2.51` but yes bash 4+ does complain about this.

Comment: Strange; `{ local a=foo; }` throws the expected error for me in 3.2.51 as well.

Comment: You're not accidentally using `zsh` for the test? (I only ask because I know some people around here [myself included] do this occasionally, and I can't remember if you are one of us :)

Comment: Oh no chance I have never used zsh. When I do `bash --version` I get this: `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`

Comment: @anubhava: really curious -- I'm using Apple's bash 3.2.51(1) too, and it gives me the error.  I did `bash --version` for the version, an `bash -c '{ local a=foo; }'` to run the command/expression, and got the 'local can only be used in a function' message.  `zsh` does allow it.

Comment: I am also wondering why it is not giving me error. `echo $0` shows `-bash`

Answer (score 0):

At least not with `{ ... }`.

The [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF) states that
code blocks created with `{ ... }` create an `anonymous function`, but all variables will still be visible to the remainder of the script.

This might be the wrong terminology as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) stated.

The [man page of bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), calling it `group command` has the following to say:

> ```
>    { list; }
>           list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated
>           with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.  The return status
>           is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), { and  }
>           are  reserved words and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recog‐
>           nized.  Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list  by
>           whitespace or another shell metacharacter.
> ```

Here is some more info in [local variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html) and their scope.

Comment: A `{...}` is not an anonymous function, which is why `local` does not work inside them.

Comment: (This is another example of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide being wrong.)